# Increasing a textField number in a for loop

Tags: java, swing

I have 81 textFields (textField_0 ... textField_80) that I want to populate my array with. How can I increase the textField number through each iteration of the for loop

I'm looking for something like this

```
for (x=0 ; x<=80 ; x++) {

    grid[x] = Integer.parseInt(textField_x.getText());

}
```

Having textField_x doesn't work, because it's obviously looking for a textField called textField_x, so what would be the correct way of doing this?

EDIT: I've tried the solution Würgspaß provided, however now I need to implement it into my frame. As a test I tried this

```
        fields[1].setColumns(10);
        fields[1].setBounds(310, 300, 32, 32);
        frame.getContentPane().add(fields[1]);
```

But it does not show up in my windowbuilder

Comment: Store them in an array, then call something like `grid[x] = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfTextfields[x].getText());` .

Comment: that's a lot of lines for code. are they stored in a file?

Comment: So would I have to store them in an array one by one?

Comment: They're not stored in a file. To give some context, I'm creating a Sudoku solver. I've got a 9x9 grid of textFields labeled from textField_0 to textField_80, and i want to store them in a 9x9 array

Comment: Yes, but maybe you already have a loop where you create all your textfields ?

Comment: @Berger I used windowBuilder to create my textFields

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) (The real problem here seems to be that you do not know how to use Window Builder.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a variable identifier in Java. For your approach to work change your code to create the TextFields like this:

```
public final static int NUM_FIELDS = 81;

TextField[] fields = new TextField[NUM_FIELDS];

for (int x=0 ; x<NUM_FIELDS ; x++) {
  fields[x] = new TextField();
}
```

and retrieve contents like this:

```
for (int x=0 ; x<NUM_FIELDS ; x++) {
    grid[x] = Integer.parseInt(fields[x].getText());
}
```

However, using 81 text fields is quite cumbersome, I would say. For my Sudoku solver I used a JTextArea for the user to type in the figures line by line. The code (in short form) looked something like this:

```
//number of fields of Sudoku
public final static int NUM_FIELDS = 81;
//ascii value for zero
public final static int ASCII_ZERO = 48;

//Sudoku figures to be entered by GUI user
private final JTextArea field;

[...]

//code to retrieve input
byte[] bytes = field.getText().getBytes();
int[] figures = new int[NUM_FIELDS];

for (int c = 0, i = 0; c < bytes.length; c++) {
    if (bytes[c]>=ASCII_ZERO && bytes[c]<(ASCII_ZERO+10)) {
        figures[i++] = (bytes[c] - asciiNull); //store entered value as int in array
    }
    //ignore newline characters but optionally handle wrong input by user using else-statements    
}
```

Of course, you could also use a two-dimensional array like `int[9][9]` or convert the entered text using `Integer.parseInt` with appropriate error handling, but in anyway you have to care about just one GUI element.

Comment: How could I implement this into windowbuilder?

Comment: @LachlanLangmead I do not know what windowbuilder is. Sounds like a proprietary GUI building tool. It probably generates code that you might change afterwards. In that case, however, you might not be able to use the tool to adjust the GUI afterwards. Therefore consider using other GUI elements like, for example, a TextArea in which the user types in all Sudoku figures line by line. That way you have got the advantage of using just one varaible to store the whole Sudoku board. a `int[][]` for example. Another advantage is that you have to convert the text to int just once.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing them in 81 different variables, go store them in one array directly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other chaps here in that putting these into an array and then iterating through is the be *better* way to do it. However, there *is* a way to do this via reflection.

Lets say that I have 100 `JTextField` named as follows:

```
JTextField tf_0 = new JTextField("0");
JTextField tf_1 = new JTextField("1");
JTextField tf_2 = new JTextField("2");
```

Up to `JTextField tf_99`.

I can then do as follows. First, I reflect the class to get its fields. Then I filter them based on their class, then the name they start with, then sort them (you may want a string comparator which goes in numeric order, rather than the default alphabetical order à la 19, 2, 20, 21).

It then creates an array and populates it with the relevant values. (You could make this all happen in streams using `mapToInt`, but that introduces a try-catch that I don't want to bother with.)

```
private int[] getTextFieldValues() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Field> fields = Stream.of(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> f.getType().equals(JTextField.class))
            .filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith("tf_"))
            .sorted((f1, f2) -> f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    int[] output = new int[fields.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
        JTextField jtf = (JTextField) fields.get(i).get(this);
        output[i] = Integer.parseInt(jtf.getText());
    }
    return output;
}
```

Now, this approach is slower, less efficient, and ... quite simply, not preferable in any way. It also requires that the fields have predictable names and that the only ones with a name starting with `tf_` are the <strike>droids</strike> fields you are looking for (or, just change or add the filtering mechanisms). But it does achieve what you want it to do.

Comment: Nice answer. Upvoted it, because you pointed out that it is not really the preferred way of doing this.